# Water and Ethanol Vapor Phase diagram for specific range

Tags: organic-chemistry, reference-request

I am looking for a Vapor Phase diagram for Water and Ethanol where Ethanol would be from 0 to 5%.

The diagrams I have found are for Ethanol concentrations of 0% to 100% and this doesn't allow me the accuracy for the range I have in my process.

If anyone could point me to a table of values that the 0 to 100% diagrams are generated from I can generate a diagram for the range I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Dortmund Data Bank](http://www.ddbst.com/ddb.html) might be a resource to start searching.

They do seem to have a page for vapour-liquid equilibrium data for the [ethanol/water mixture](http://www.ddbst.com/en/EED/VLE/VLE%20Ethanol%3BWater.php).

On a first view, however, the data seem to be for less than atmospheric pressures only and are compiled from [*Ind. Eng. Chem.*, **1942**, 34, 1501–1504](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ie50396a019).